# Faulting module name: vrfcore.dll, version: 6.3.9600.16384 and Exception Code : 0x80000003

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows, winforms, visual-studio

I created a winform application in VS express 2013 for windows Desktop and sql server 2012, everything runs beautifully and as expected both in debug and release modes but when i try to run the exe out of the visual studio (by clicking on .exe) it crashes and i found  **Faulting module name: vrfcore.dll, version: 6.3.9600.16384 and Exception Code  : 0x80000003** in the event logger[As in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5BqN.png)
,i have written the code in vb.net, can any one help me with this

Comment: vrfcore.dll comes from ApplicationVerifier. Are you running the application under ApplicationVerifier?

Answer (score 9):

vrfcore.dll is used by Application Verifier and it creates registry entry also in some cases.
Make sure you are not deleting or changing anything else while doing the following step:- 
**Goto Registry editor-> win+R->regedit->HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->SOFTWARE->Microsoft->Windows NT->CurrentVersion-> Image File Execution Options -> (Your application name.exe).**
->Right Click and export the registry settings for backup.
->Delete the registry entry for your application and try to run.

Hope it works.

Comment: This totally saved me, thanks a ton. Although I still don't understand why it got messed up in the first place, thanks Microsoft -_-.

Comment: Months trying to figure out what was broken on my dev env. Thanks a lot.